# Is there a Sybase unwired platform Equivalent?

Tags: synchronization, data-synchronization, equivalent, sup, sap-smp

I built an IOS mobile application based on a Siebel CRM application. All synchronization system is made with SUP (Sybase unwired platform) and web services.

SUP is a good product but very too "black box" for us.

Indeed, it build a CDB (Cache database) based on web services and provides a relative good way to make synchronization between the siebel database  and the local DB.

I Googled if there is a similar solution to SUP but without success.

So, does anyone know any solution?

I would like a solution which build a db based on web services and provides a good way to synchronize data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SMP 3 or HCPms. It is the latest mobile solutions from SAP. It has offline capabilities where it creates local databases in your mobile devices.

Comment: Hi MidhunVP, thanks for the reply, but I don't need an SAP solution for the structure. Do you know any other solution?